# how to check all checkbox in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

by calling the method addAllMarkers(item) I want all checkbox related to an item  will be checked.

in my index.html i have :

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">

        <a href="#" ng-if="item.children" ng-click="addAllMarkers(item)">{{ item.title }}</a>

        <input ng-if="!item.children" class="align"
                    type="checkbox"  ng-checked="item.checked" ng-click="checkItem(item)"
                   />

        <a href="#" ng-if="!item.children" ng-click="checkItem(item)">

                {{ item.title }} </a>
</li>
```

in my controller I have :

```
$scope.checkItem = function(item){

 if(item.checked== undefined || item.checked== true){

     itemProvider.remove(item);
      item.checked = false;   }
else{
     $scope.markers=itemProvider.addMarkers(item);
      item.checked = true; 
}
```

this method is used to check or uncheck just one checkbox;
in addAllMarkers I have the folowing code, but it doesn't work :(

```
 $scope.addAllMarkers = function (item){
 for(var i in item){
    if(!item[i].children){
    item[i].checked = true;
 }}
 .....

}
```

Comment: You are passing the object `item` to the function `addAllMarkers`, but in this function you are treating `item` as an array. Maybe you want to pass `items` instead.

Comment: @Michael P. He's not treating this as an array the for (var key in object) is a supported syntax in Javascript.

Comment: @Fadwa el kebraoui since you want all to be true the if statement is extraneous. Also you should use the hasOwnProperty check when iterating over properties in an object in this manner.

Comment: @tuckerjt07 I'm aware of the syntax `for (var key in obj)`, but if you look at the template, `item` has a property `title` displayed in a `<a>` tag. As `item['title'].children` or `item['title'].checked` is a nonsense, I keep thinking OP thought iterating over an array.